# How to save map by using map_server package according to the topics?

Tags: ros, slam

I used the multi_map_merge package to merge map from robot 1 and robot 2. But when I used `rosrun map_server map_saver -f ~/map`, the map is only saved the merge map which is from `/map` topic. But I also would like to save map from `/tb3_0/map` and `/tb3_1/map` topics. I would like to ask how to save map according to the map topics? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can remap the default costmap topic when invoking the map_server node. All that is required is to set the map to your costmap topic.

**For example:**

```
rosrun map_server map_saver -f mymap map:=/move_base/global_costmap/costmap
```

Here the topic from which the map will be saved is `/move_base/global_costmap/costmap`

You can substitute your own topics, i.e., `/tb3_0/map` and `/tb3_0/map` instead of the `/move_base/global_costmap/costmap` to create the respective maps

**Feel free to explore the ROS Wiki for more details:**

Link to map_server documentation: http://wiki.ros.org/map_server